# In which order - if any - are nodes drawn in a GEF editor?

Tags: layout, graph, eclipse-gef, draw2d

I'm trying to plug a (very) simple graph layout algorithm into my GEF editor. I do it by simply adding `calculateX()` and `calculateY()` methods to my `NodeEditPart`s' `refreshVisuals()` (the graph figure has an `XYLayout` obviously).

It does work, albeit only for those nodes, which have a connection to another node, of which they are the source. When I try to access the constraints for nodes to which the node in question has a connection, of which it is the target, I get a `NullPointerException`.

I'm *guessing* that this is to do with the order in which nodes are drawn in GEF.

I'm also *guessing* that there is no such thing as an element parser checking which elements will have to be drawn first, but rather that elements are either drawn in the order they appear in a `List`, or concurrently via the `EditPartFactory` (which, however, must get its input from some sort of ordered collection in the model).

But how is it really done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GEF the elements are drawn in the order they appear in the list returned by `getModelChildren()` (I don't remember if from start to end or backwards, but you can check the code)

Nevertheless, I couldn't understand what exactly was your problem, so if you can provide more details I may help you some more.